# How to use aws_account_utils to create an AWS account ? Getting error : cannot load such file -- aws_account_utils

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use AWSAccountUtils in my project to create AWS account. I have installed gem aws_account_utils too. What more do I need to do or what is that I am missing ? In my controller I have defined following function and code is :

```
def create_aws_account

    require 'aws_account_utils'

    @account_details = []
    @account_values = {}

    aws_utils = AwsAccountUtils::AwsAccountUtils.new()

    details = {   'fullName'     => 'Devanshu Kumar',
                  'company'      => 'ABC',
                  'addressLine1' => 'CP, Bund Garden Road',
                  'city'         => 'Pune',
                  'state'        => 'Maharastra',
                  'postalCode'   => '411007',
                  'phoneNumber'  => '1234567890',
                  'guess'        => 'Test Account Dev' }

    resp = aws_utils.create_account(account_name: 'My Test Account Devanshu Kumar',
                                    account_email: 'devanshu.kumar@abc.com',
                                    account_password: 'password',
                                    account_details: details)

    @account_values = {:account_number => data_disk.resp}
    @account_details.push @account_values

    render :json => { created_aws_account: account_details }

end
```

[AWS Account Details Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxrFF.png)

Comment: Hi..Please guide me for this issue. I need to resolve it fast.

Comment: I have resolved the above error by getting lib files in the lib folder. However I am getting another error now - unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055). Firefox version used is v45.0, Selenium-webdriver is 2.53.4 and capybara (2.14.0). Still I am getting the error. Please advise if there is any issue with any version.